# Use material icons along with text in axes label

Tags: angular, angular-material, chart.js

I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRuj90oHOPU to get material icons to represent the labels. Since material icons only have code available, I used \u before them to get the unicode representation (Not sure if this is how it is intended to be used). Each label is stored in the labels array as "Random1 \uf10d".

Though am able to view the icon... I have some texts attached with each pin - these texts do not show up as expected.

eg:
[image]

Am I using the code wrongly for this to happen? Or are material icons not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the video, I had provided font-family for the ticks on y axis. However, the order of these values had an impact on how the data was processed.
Instead of

```
ticks: {
           autoSkip: false,
           font: {
                    family: "'Material Icons', 'Material Icons Outlined', 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
                    size: 12
                 }
        }
```

I needed to use:

```
ticks: {
           autoSkip: false,
           font: {
                    family: "'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif, 'Material Icons', 'Material Icons Outlined',",
                    size: 12
                 }
        }
```